# Grabbing data from two HTML forms from the same page

Tags: php, html

So I've searched through some posts, and I've seen that I can't use a HTML form within another HTML form.
Like:

```
<form method="post" action="x.php">
    <input type="..."/>
    <form method="post" action="x.php">
        <input type="..."/>
    </form>
</form>
```

Ok, but my problem is that I want to make a different page, which contains HTML code like this:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['vote']) && $_GET['vote']=='yes'){
    echo 'vote successfully inserted';
}

# gets the email value from MAIN form
$email = isset($_POST['email'] : $_POST['email'] : NULL;

#grab the infos from bd for the user with that email,
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT name,email,vote FROM tbl WHERE email=:e');
$stmt->execute(array(':e'=>$email));
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){
    if($row->vote == 'no'){ # IF THE USER DIDN'T VOTED, THEN
        if(isset($_POST['vote'])){ # IF THE <a> IS PRESSED, UPDATE DB
            $sql = "UPDATE tbl SET vote='yes' WHERE email=:e";
            $s = $db->prepare($sql);
            $s->execute(array(':e'=>$email));
        }
    }
    ?>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Email</td>
            <td>Address</td>
            <td>Vote</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row->name;?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row->email;?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row->address;?></td>
            <td>
                <form method="POST" action="" id="SECOND">
                    <a href="index.php?vote=yes" name="vote">VOTE!</a>
                 </form>
             </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
<?php } // end while() ?>
```

Then, under this `<table>`, I have another form:

```
<form action="" method="POST" id="MAIN>
    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="email"><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Login" name="submit"/>
</form>
```

The project is about a electoral campaign, where a user can 'login' with this email address, and submit his vote.
So,

1. when the user requests the page, the MAIN form will pop-up, he will fill in his email, and will press submit.
2. he is redirected to the same page (I'm hiding the MAIN form), and the table will pop-up.
3. now, the user can select his favorite candidate, and press on the `<a>` link - his vote will be stored in db, updating the vote field from, initially 'no' to 'yes'.

Now, the prob is that when the `<a>` link is pressed, the update in the db doesn't take place.

Comment: so in essence you can vote as someone else - nice !

Comment: @birdspider No you can't. The site logic is with something else instead email, but that system isn't used in England or USA, so I wrote email instead that unique person identifier.

Comment: Do you want to get the data from one form to another in the case of submitting from any one of them?

Comment: @sємsєм As I stated in the main post, 1st, when the user requests the index page, the MAIN form will show-up (and only the MAIN form). Then, after the user fills-in his infos and presses 'submit', then he will be redirected in the same page (index.php), where now I'm hiding the MAIN form, and instead the <table> will be shown. Something like this:  Name=(get the name from bd), Email=(get the email from db), Vote=(if the user didn''t vote, then 'no' will appear). If the user already voted, then instead 'no', the 'yes' message will appear, and a message will prevent the user for voting again.

Comment: Thanks for the tips you gave guys, but nothing work. Instead, the only hack that I've found, is that I've re-wrote the SECOND form, and I've added a hidden field which contains the $email value, and then I added a .php file to process the form, and in that file, I'm looking to see if the hidden field is set, and if it is, then I perform the UPDATE query, based on that hidden input field.  This is for who will be looking for answers for a problem similar to mine.

Answer (score 0):

The reason the  link doesn't update the database is because the form is not being submitted.  Change the  to an

```
<input type="submit" value="VOTE!">
```

Comment: And what may be the cause for not being submitted? The syntax is correct, and as for the logic: only if the <a> link is pressed, then update the db. I can't see any prob here :(

Comment: Nesting an anchor inside of a form does not submit the form.

Comment: I've tried all the possibilities: <input type="submit">, <input type="button" onclick="called js function here">, <button type="submit">Vote</button>. Still, nothing works. As I stated, I've created even a js function for that <input type="button"> element, where I'm returning window.location.href="index.php?vote=yes". And in vain...